# Create a Minimal Hello World UWP app

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, c++-cx

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to create a simple C++/Cx Universal Windows Platform application. I need to start from scratch, without any kind of finery.

When I create a new "blank" project I end up with 2 `XAML` files (each with a `.cpp` and a `.h` file linked) and a directory full of generated code. Some of these files are even generated after the first compilation. This is not ok for my case, I would like to have a single `main()` function with minimal code possible to run an Hello World application, with NO automatically generated code.

In one of the generated files (`App.g.hpp`) I found the `main()` method but I didn't find a way to write my own in a non-generated file:

```
int __cdecl main(::Platform::Array<::Platform::String^>^ args)
{
    (void)args; // Unused parameter
    ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(ref new ::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback(
        [](::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams^ p) {
            (void)p; // Unused parameter
            auto app = ref new ::MinimalUWP::App();
        }));
}
```

Is there a template available to have a **true** blank UWP project?

Comment: What programming language? The question is tagged [tag:c++], the code uses [tag:c++-cx].

Comment: C++/Cx, corrected

Comment: If you need a barebones UWP application, don't use the project wizard to create one. This requires that you know, what you are doing. Using C++/WinRT is likely easier. See [C++ - Introducing C++/WinRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt745094.aspx).

Comment: I also tried without the wizard and it works fine. The problem is that at the end of execution it appears an error saying that my "app is not activated"

Comment: So you have a different problem from the one you were asking about in this question?

Comment: No, the problem is always the same. I can't run a simple Hello World application without UWP errors

Comment: But your question is stating, that you cannot create a barebones UWP application. So which one is it? Those are two different problems.

Comment: How are two different problems? I need a main() function where I can put code in it. When I say "a simple Hello World app" I mean a straightforward console print

Comment: You are focused on your ultimate goal, and every problem you encounter looks like it is the same problem to you. It isn't. You have so far stated 2 **distinct** problems: `1` Creating a UWP app produces too much auto-generated code. `2` Running a barebones UWP application exhibits a runtime error. Those are different problems. If you don't want auto-generated code, don't use C++/CX. You can use either C++ with WRL or C++/WinRT. Besides that, a UWP application must be deployed and registered (and the system prepared for side-loading).

Comment: Ok. Sorry you're right, this is getting very confusing for me considering that my goal should be the most simple one. So you're telling me that I can use a language different than C++/CX but still have a legit UWP application? Is the auto-generation of code an intrinsic feature of C++/CX?

Comment: Sort of. C++/CX will always generate C++ code to implement the language extensions (like `ref class`). The *App.g.hpp* file, on the other hand, is part of the tool chain tied to C++/CX, that create the underpinnings like entry point, and XAML support. There is no immediate XAML support in C++ (with or without WRL), nor in C++/WinRT (as of the current release). Both C++ (with WRL) and C++/WinRT allow you to write genuine UWP applications without any auto-generated code. [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/10.0.15063.0/Samples/Syndication) is a minimalistic sample.

Comment: Sorry, that was a Desktop application using Windows Runtime types. A fairly minimalistic UWP application can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/10.0.15063.0/Samples/XamlCode).

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks. Do I need to download the github repository to work with C++/WinRT? I have a winrt folder in my Windows 10 sdk installation but it doesn't look to match the same code (I can't find the `Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationT` class in the sdk)

Comment: You have to clone the GitHub repository to use C++/WinRT. The *winrt* folder in the Windows SDK only contains IDL and header files for the Windows Runtime types to be used from C and C++. The C++/WinRT header files, on the other hand, contain Standard C++ classes, auto-generated from the *Windows.winmd* file, plus a bit of support code. C++/WinRT is the successor to C++/CX, and may eventually replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by myself using this code:

```
ref class UwpApp : public ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application
{
protected:
   virtual void OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e) override
   {
      // Use e->Arguments as main arguments
   }
};

int __cdecl main(::Platform::Array<::Platform::String^>^ args)
{
   ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(ref new ::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback(
      [](::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams^ p) {
      auto app = ref new UwpApp();
   }));
}
```

Thanks @IInspectable, at the end I sticked with C++/CX and it worked!

Comment: Note that console output currently isn't supported. You can call `OutputDebugString("Hello, world")` but it will never show to a normal user. What is the eventual purpose of your application?